# Working backwards with Determinants.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The determinant of A is -2. Find $\det(3A^TA^3)$. You may leave your answer as a product of integers.

What I did was this:

$$\det(3A^TA^3)$$

$$\det(3A^T)\det(A^3)$$

$$3\det(A^T)(\det(A))^3$$

This is the part where I became confused;

$$3\det(A^T)(-2)^3 $$

That's as far as I got, and looking at the solution what I was doing was correct, however the solution for it does this;

$$\det(3A^T)\det(A)^{3}$$
$$(3^3)\det(A)\det(A)^{3}$$
$$(27)(-2)^4$$
$$(27)(16)$$
$$432$$

Now the part that confuses me about this question is , where does the other power of three come from in the line, and what happened to the transpose?

$$(3^3)\det(A)\det(A)^{3}$$

Comment: Sure thing, I'll do that right away.

Comment: @user1327636, I will add to the two excellent answers you've received, that the problem as stated cannot be solved -- you need to know that $A$ is $3\times 3$ (or some other specific size), else there is no way to pull the $3$ out of the determinant uniquely.

Comment: @vadim123 well spotted, I embarrassingly ignored that no dimension was specified!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\det(A) = \det(A^{T})$ (can you see why this is?); furthermore, for an $n \times n$ matrix, $\det(kA) = k^{n}\det(A)$, where $k$ is a constant.

Answer (score 2):

As an answer to your first question, consider the following two facts:

1. The determinant of a matrix is equal to the determinant of its transpose.
2. If $A$ is a square matrix, and $B$ is obtained from $A$ by multiplying one row (or column) by a constant $c$, then $\det(B)=c\det(A)$.

Notice that from fact number 2 that an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ satisfies the equation:

$$\det(cA)=c^n\det(A)$$